# Quartz job triggering from Config.groovy

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler, grails-plugin, grails-config

I have the following Quartz job running in my application:

```
class ScraperJob {
    def scraperService

    static triggers = {
        cron name: 'scraperTrigger', cronExpression: "0 0 * * * ?"  // run every minute
    }

    def execute(){
        try {
            scraperService.storing()
            log.info "${new Date()} - Scraping went smoothly."
        }
        catch(IOException) { // Connexion problem
            log.error "${new Date()} - Method: parsing >> Connexion down or interrupted while parsing !"
        }
        catch(SAXException) { // Any SAXParser exception
            log.error "${new Date()} - Method: parsing >> Parser error."
        }
        finally { // if not closed, the application crashes when the connexion fails
            scraperService.slurper.finalize()
            scraperService.parser.finalize()
        }
  }
}
```

I would like to know if it is possible to set the `triggers` property from the `Config.groovy` file. If it is, could you explain how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have no idea if this would actually work because i'm not sure when the quartz jobs get configured but in theory it would seem to work.  You could probably see how you could also make this much more dynamic if you have more than one job.

Config.groovy

```
quartz.yourCronJobName="0 0 * * * ?"
```

BootStrap.groovy

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as ConfigHolder
...
def cronExpression = ConfigHolder.config.yourCronJobName
ScraperJob.triggers.cronExpression = cronExpression
```

Good luck.  Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Ah ah, I am impressed ! That is exactly it. Than you very much

Comment: Oh, actually I thought it worked because my job was triggered exactly when I was telling him to, but it was because it kept running in background. 
I do not manage yet to start it from BootStrap, but I am on it :)

Comment: Shouldn't all the keys be set? (name & cronExpression). 
Also, how can you add more than one trigger? And remove a trigger? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I eventually did it:

**Config.groovy**

```
scraperJob= "0 * * * * ?"
```

**ScraperJob.groovy**

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as ConfigHolder

class ScraperJob {

  static triggers = {
        cron cronExpression: ConfigHolder.config.scraperJob // Calling the ScraperJob set in Config.groovy
    }
  def execute(){ ... }
}
```